Cloud function works as http, but doesn't work as a scheduled function
I have a daily scheduled function as follows:
export const dailyExecutedFunction = async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    // some other code

    setRoutineAnalytics();

  } catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error(error);
    functions.logger.error(
      'Something went wrong with daily executed function',
      { structuredData: true }
    );
  }
};

And the setRoutineAnalytics function:
export async function setRoutineAnalytics(): Promise<void> {
  try {
    functions.logger.info('A');

    const date = getDateFromDaysAgo(1);

    const dailyRoutines = await firestore
      .collection('today_routines')
      .where('date', '==', date)
      .get(); // around 300 - 400 docs

    functions.logger.info('B');

    // update routine analytics with some other code

  } catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error(error);
    functions.logger.error(
      'Something went wrong with setting routine analytics',
      { structuredData: true }
    );
  }
}


I have verified that setRoutineAnalytics works fine when I call it manually using a http cloud function (functions.https.onRequest). However, when it doesn't work when called by a scheduled function (functions.pubsub).
Inspecting the logs explorer, 'A' gets logged but 'B' does not. There are also no error messages that are logged.
What could be the issue here?

Cloud functions are event driven services. If you want to schedule functions you have to use cloud schedular.

@RoopaM Yes I am using a scheduler using functions.pubsub. I've been using it for other functions and it works fine. But it does not execute this one specific function completely.

Can you have a look at this StackOverflow thread?

I managed to make it work by adding a limit to the firestore query. Not sure why this is the case though.
    const dailyRoutines = await firestore
      .collection('today_routines')
      .where('date', '==', date)
      .limit(100) // added limit
      .get();

